# Push git repository to remote subversion with history

Tags: git, svn, merge, git-svn

I'd like to push my existing git repository with its' complete history into a remote subversion repository via `git-svn`. Is this possible without losing the commit history? I already rebased my changes so, there is only a master branch up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, dcommit will preserve the history granted you have rebased (thus have no merge commits to be pushed). Username at svn for all revisions will keep the credentials of the pusher though.

Comment: I think you didn't understand what I meant. I want to push an **existing git repository in which I worked for a while** initial to a subversion remote. In all tutorials there is shown, that I first have to create a subversion repository and clone it via `git svn clone`, but I want to push it directly with all of is history. I cannot run dcommit before I cloned the repo because git svn won't know my remote repo.

Comment: Technically you can create a new svn repo, add it as a remote to git (manually edit .git/config) and then do `git rebase svn/trunk && git svn dcommit`

Comment: Is it a good idea to add it to git as a remote? What will happen if I accidently run `git push`?

Comment: I made it now as follows:                                                                             created a svn repository, `git svn clone svn:/path/to/repo`, `cd /repo/name`, `git pull /path/to/local/existing repo`, `git svn rebase`, `git svn dcommit`. Worked for me

Comment: @uloco I didn't mean adding as a regular git remote, rather an svn remote, see the `svn-remote` section of the `.git/config` file of your git-svn'ed repo. Doing git svn clone into a new git repository is also an option, of course.